Unable to fetch basechain transcation
I created a wallet using this code :
from eth_account import Account

# Create a new Ethereum wallet
account = Account.create()
private_key = account.key.hex()
address = account.address

print("Private Key:", private_key)
print("Address:", address)


and then i sent a $0.01 worth ETH on basechain network. Now the transaction is visible on basescan but when i try to retrieve transactions using code it says no transactions.
import requests
import constants

wallet_address = '0x62103CFe6629F148eB6B4683449AD99049ACDe8F'

def fetch_transactions(address):
    params = {
        'module': 'account',
        'action': 'txlist',
        'address': address,
        'startblock': 0,
        'endblock': 99999999,
        'sort': 'asc',
        'apikey': constants.BASESCAN_API_KEY
    }
    
    response = requests.get('https://api.basescan.org/api', params=params)
    data = response.json()

    if data['status'] == '1':
        transactions = data['result']
        print(f'Transactions for address {address}:')
        for tx in transactions:
            print(f"Hash: {tx['hash']}, Block: {tx['blockNumber']}, From: {tx['from']}, To: {tx['to']}, Value: {tx['value']} ETH")
    else:
        print(f"Error fetching transactions: {data['message']}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fetch_transactions(wallet_address)


Note that this code gives me correct transactions for another wallet address that is connected to metamask.

This is not a Python issue per se. Try BaseScan API Support
